# RDS and pt-table-sync. Tables can't sync. How to get around this?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, percona, rds

I'm trying to sync to tables with the pt-table-sync.
The problem is that the RDS `bilong_format` is setted to `MIXED` and the tool needs `STATEMENT`. And we don't have super privilegies to change it.

How can I get around this and sync my tables?

The error is described below:

```
This tool requires binlog_format=STATEMENT, but the current binlog_format is set to MIXED and an error occurred while attempting to change it.  If running MySQL 5.1.29 or newer, setting binlog_format requires the SUPER privilege.  You will need to manually set binlog_format to 'STATEMENT' before running this tool.
```

Answer (score 2):

## SUGGESTION

When you run `pt-table-sync`, do not use the `--execute` option as it may require all the necessary grants. Try using `--sync-to-master` and `--print` and redirect the output to a SQL text file. If the the SQL text file gets generated, look inside the SQL text file.

*If the SQL text file contains only `REPLACE` statements*, simply run the SQL text file on the Master. It will replicate everything to the Slave.

*If it contains even one `DELETE` statement*, you are better off dropping the RDS Slave and spinning up a new read-only RDS Slave.

Give it a Try !!!